# Iterating through a loop at the same rate with different variables

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to iterate through a loop at the same time. Not sure if I am wording the question properly.

For example, I need the difference of column 1 from both dataframes to be stored in `Calibrated Power 0 [dBm]` or column 4 of df. I need column 2 to be stored in the `Calibrated Power 10 [dBm]` column. At the moment, the same data is being copied to columns 4-6 of df

```
attenuator_power = [0, 10, 30]
for i in range(1, 3):
    ydata_sans_att = df_sans_attenuator.iloc[:, i]
    ydata_df = df.iloc[:, i]
    for j in attenuator_power:
        df['Calibrated Power {} [dBm]'.format(j)] = ydata_df - ydata_sans_att
```

Comment: So do you want all combinations of i and j? As in, do you want 1, 0 and 2, 10 and 3, 30 or do you want 1, 0 and 1,10 and 1,30 etc?

Comment: 1, 0 and 2, 10 and 3, 30 @mauve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you pair them:

```
for i, j in zip(range(1,3), attenuator_power):
    ydata_sans_att = df_sans_attenuator.iloc[:, i]
    ydata_df = df.iloc[:, i]
    df['Calibrated Power {} [dBm]'.format(j)] = ydata_df - ydata_sans_att
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that this was even an option

Comment: And it works for as many variables as you want - you aren't limited to 2.

Answer (score 1):

@mauve already gave a great answer, but here is another option:

```
for i, j in enumerate(attenuator_power, 1):
    ydata_sans_att = df_sans_attenuator.iloc[:, i]
    ydata_df = df.iloc[:, i]
    df['Calibrated Power {} [dBm]'.format(j)] = ydata_df - ydata_sans_att
```